# Getting Album Art for music player Android (error)

Tags: java, android, mobile, compiler-errors

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException /  retriever.setDataSource(path );

```
private byte[] getArt(String path){
     MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
     retriever.setDataSource(path );
     byte[] art = retriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
     retriever.release();
     return art;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource(file.getPath());
byte [] data = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```